# Using JMapper for source as List of Objects

Tags: java, modelmapper

I want to use `JMapper` to map a `List<Pojo>` which is my source to `List<DTO>` which is my destination. Currently, I'm making use of `ModelMapper` but it is not very efficient. I tried searching but couldn't find any solution. Can we map List to List using JMapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. We can use following technique -

```
List<Pojo> response = repository.findAll();
JMapper<DTO, Pojo> mapper = new JMapper<>(DTO.class, Pojo.class);
List<DTO> result = response.stream().map(temp-> mapper.getDestination(temp))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: could you please share the JMapper API configurations for the above scenario?

Comment: I used annotation based configuration. Kind of as given here - >https://www.baeldung.com/jmapper#annotations

Comment: Thank you @chetan for the response basically I have a issue with the JMapper mapping that has list of objects inside the main JSON object.

Comment: I'm confused @SRMKumar with your doubt. Do you want to map List of Objects to JSON or map List of Object which is inside a JSON Object to some List of another type? If it is the first then I don't think there is much issue. If second then still no issue as you can pull out your List of Object out of the JSON. For mapping again you can use annotation based mapping.